# Clean Install of Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: system-installation

When I was installing Ubuntu 13.10, I thought it gives me an option to wipe out my WIN XP It did not now I have both Xp and Ubuntu, and I have to choose every time I boot.  How do I change it so that I only have UBUNTU, I don't care if I loose all with my WIN XP

Comment: Make a bootable disc or pendrive of 13.10, boot from it, format xp system drive(normally C: drive), then install there

Answer (score 1):

You can remove Windows without reinstalling Ubuntu using [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller).

Answer (score 0):

I will reinstall the ubuntu software and select the custon option, It will show you the breakdown of the HD, Format the drive, Then select the full space of the HD for the installation. 
One issue though, I would not be too quick to remove Winxp as like all operating system they can become corrupted & a backup operating system would be handy if you dont have another machine!